# How to write YACC grammar that builds a tree of tokens etc?

Tags: c, grammar, bison, yacc

I have read about YACC,  and I have seen a few examples  of simple toy programs. But I have never seen a practical example that demonstrates how to build a tree of tokens and so on, nor has it been easy to find an example using Google search. Can someone provide one example of how to generate the tree using YACC? C or C++ is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that you just build the tree in your semantic actions, with rules like this:

```
expr: expr '+' expr  { $0 = make_op_node(OP_ADD, $1, $3); }
```

That would be backed by an implementation function like:

```
Node* make_op_node(enum OP opcode, Node* left, Node* right) {
  Node* rv = malloc(sizeof *rv);
  rv->opcode = opcode;
  rv->left = left;
  rv->right = right;
  return rv;
}
```

The `Node` struct is most likely to be a discriminated `union`, since possible opcodes would have to include things like constants and identifier references.